# Default connections hold by JedisPool

Tags: performance, redis, connection-pooling

I am integrating `redis` with `ofbiz` by using `jedis client`. 
 One redis server is being used by different application. 
My question is

1. How many connection will be hold by `JedisPool` by default.
2. If I create multiple `JedisPool` will it effect `redis` performance

Note : I am creating `JedisPool` with default configuration in another application.

```
client = new JedisPool(ip, port);
```

Is there any better approach?, suggest me. Thanks

**Update** : Initiating `redis server` with default configuratoin user `spring data`

```
<bean id="connectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
    p:host-name="${app.cache.redis.host}" p:port="${app.cache.redis.port}" p:password="${app.cache.redis.password}" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***1) How many connection will be hold by JedisPool by default***

By using JedisPool with this instantiation,

```
client = new JedisPool(ip, port);
```

you are using a `GenericObjectPoolConfig` from apache-commons-pool.

The default configuration for this generic pool is:

```
DEFAULT_MAX_TOTAL = 8
DEFAULT_MAX_IDLE = 8
DEFAULT_MIN_IDLE = 0
```

***2) If I create multiple JedisPool will it effect redis performance***

Yes and no. If you create multiple JedisPool, you will have more clients connected to Redis. But Redis can support a lot of connected clients with very good performance.

You can set the Redis max client authorized number in redis.conf (for example 10000 clients max).

```
maxclients 10000
```

or at startup :

```
./redis-server --maxclients 10000
```

or with redis-cli :

```
127.0.0.1:6379> config set maxclients 10000
```

In the default configuration, the number of authorized clients is unlimited.

Depending of your use case, you can have multiple JedisPool, or simply increase the size of your JedisPool (to have more than 8 connections).

Comment: It looks ilke I cannot use JedisPool on an address other than localhost, somewhere is a bug in pool implementation, it tries to connect to localhost and fails...